# How Do I Restart Chromium Once Closed?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, openbox

I am currently network booting a Raspberry Pi and using Openbox I autostart chromium, is it possible that if a user presses close or minimise I can programatically restart chromium in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a shell command to restart the command as soon as it finishes.

Assuming your openbox config for autostarting stuff lets you put in shell snippets you can use

```sh
while true; do
  chromium
done
```

If you have to specify just *one* command in your openbox config you can wrap that in a string to hand to `sh`:

```sh
sh -c 'while true; do chromium; done'
```

Or you could put it in a script and make that executable (`chmod +x my-script-file.sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
  chromium
done
```

and then tell openbox to autostart the my-script-file.sh.

Comment: This works perfectly when Chromium is closed, is possible to do something similar when it has been minimised?

Comment: @danfs sorry I don't know. You can have a look at the docs of [`xdotool`](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)  and write a script with that. But you should ask a new question about that.  Your specific question from the top seems to be answered then.